# Prevent multiple iframes from loading on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm setting up a client's website. It loads multiple videos from Vimeo in iframes. On mobile that presents a problem since the page takes long to load. I would like not to load them on mobile.

My problem is I only figured out how to stop the load for one iframe by using the following script:

```html
<script>
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 720px)").matches) {
  let iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-1')
  iframe.src = iframe.getAttribute('data-src')
}
</script>
```

What do I need to do to select all iframes on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('iframe')` in order to select all the iframes.

It will return to u a NodeList (not a regular array).

You can iterate over it, and do the same attribute replacement.

```
const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
Array.from(iframes).forEach((iframe) => {
  iframe.src = iframe.getAttribute('data-src')
});
```